# Architecture a project without eclipse IDE

Tags: c++

I have been using Eclipse/CDT for all my C/C++ based projects so far, they were of low complexity but had medium side codebase, for sometime I have had a feeling that IDE is posing some sort of limitation during work.

Nowadays I have most projects that are multi-platforms, modular and supposed to include plugin design, I think go on like this could litter the whole thing so I am thinking to follow more standard approach that not to use any IDE., I am aware, that I have to manually create my folder structure, use gnu autotools or cmake, but I still have following doubts;

1. Can I abandon Eclipse and I am correct that it more of a problem than any help when a software is complex. Or can still use eclipse no matter how complex code is?
2. Do I have to give up "code completion" feature that IDEs offer and start remembering API function names, thats very problematic when using new API each time.
3. When a single file changes how does the manually laid out build system knows only to compile that file.

Any other suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: I am afraid that the only real question is 3, and need to be reformulated. Using a IDE is a personal choice. Furthermore, using an ide project should not interfere to use other IDE with the same project. For instance, I have been using Geany all my like with CMake. Now I moved to SublimeText or QtCreator, I load the CMakeLists.txt to enable code completion but keep compiling the same way (console). And all those trash files are not included in the corresponding repo. So, try the different choices and choose the one you like more.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths to some extent yes, but now I have to also decide whether to migrate from eclipse!

Comment: You can use Eclipse with any manual build system. I **never** let Eclipse manage my project for me. I always use either **autotools** or plain Makefile. Just start the project selecting "MakeFile Project"->"Empty Project". Then just use Eclipse as the amazing file editor/program debugger etc.. that it is.

Comment: Also I have not found a tool as good as eclipse for **autocomplete**, **refactoring code**, **search/replace** etc... Frankly it is probably the Eclipse build system that is the limiting factor. Use a different build system as per @John Zwinck's anser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Can I abandon Eclipse and I am correct that it more of a problem than any help when a software is complex. Or can still use eclipse no matter how complex code is?

One way to use Eclipse is to make your build system independently (e.g. with CMake, SCons, or manually crafted Makefiles), and just point Eclipse to your project directory to edit the files.

2. Do I have to give up "code completion" feature that IDEs offer and start remembering API function names, thats very problematic when using new API each time.

No, Eclipse can do autocomplete for projects for which it did not create the Makefiles.

3. When a single file changes how does the manually laid out build system knows only to compile that file.

Any competent build system will analyze dependencies for you.  Certainly CMake and SCons and a bunch of other ones will.

---

Overall, one benefit I have found of *not* using the build system that comes with a particular IDE is that it enables coworkers to use whichever tools they prefer.  If you use Eclipse to generate Makefiles, then people cannot easily add files to your project using Emacs, for example.  It's better to keep the build system separate from the IDE for this reason, and for other reasons such as that the Makefiles generated by CMake are of higher quality than those generated by NetBeans for example (again, in my experience).

---

An exception to all this might be Windows.  There, Microsoft's tools rule the roost, and you might better leverage them as much as you can if you're developing apps for Windows itself.

Comment: I use Linux for all of development and Windows only when testing them.